# R table producing unexpected results

Tags: r

I've loaded a tibble into R - example:

```r
population<-read_excel<-("file.xlsx")

 A tibble: 4 x 2
  Ethnicity    Population
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 Hispanic         543781
2 Not Hispanic    3692614
3 Unknown               0
4 Total           4236395
```

I'm now having trouble when I call any sort of table function on it. Basic example:

```r
table(population) produces

            Population
Ethnicity      0 543781 3692614 4236395
  Hispanic     0      1       0       0
  Not Hispanic 0      0       1       0
  Total        0      0       0       1
  Unknown      1      0       0       0
```

Using another package - example `tabyl` from `Janitor` produces:

```r
tabyl(population)

Error in tabyl.data.frame(population) : 
  if calling on a data.frame, specify unquoted column names(s) to tabulate.  Did you mean to call tabyl() on a vector?

tabyl(population$Ethnicity, population$Population) creates:
 population$Ethnicity n percent
               Hispanic 1    0.25
           Not Hispanic 1    0.25
                  Total 1    0.25
                Unknown 1    0.25
```

Previously, I was able to produce a crosstab of Ethnicity and Population, which is what I was expecting, and previously was able to produce. Here's what I produced previously using `tabyl`:

Ethnicity   n   percent
Hispanic    543781  51.6
Not Hispanic    3692614 48
Unknown 0   0.5

Image of table:
[image]

I am not sure what I've changed in R to cause it to behave differently.
Anyone know why I'm getting the additional 0s and 1s in the table?

I've tried clearing the R environment and restarting R.

Comment: `table` is doing exactly what it is supposed to: giving counts of distinct combinations of all variables in the frame. It does not make sense to me to have "population" be one of those, since that value is effectively continuous (discrete) and not a categorical/ordinal variable.

Comment: Perhaps you could make this reproducible using a small sample of your data, provide the output from `dput(.)` (with that sample), and give the expected results given that sample. Thanks.

Comment: hi - thanks for the comments. I am a fairly new user, so I apologize in advance, since I'm not sure that I understand your comments. The dataframe I posted is the entire dataframe in this case - although I do have more complicated ones that have suddenly changed behavior as well. Population is numeric, but it's effectively a categorical variable here - it's just the total population for that ethnic group.

Comment: calling dput gets: dput(population)
structure(list(Ethnicity = c("Hispanic", "Not Hispanic", "Unknown", 
"Total"), Population = c(543781, 3692614, 0, 4236395)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: You will need to explain how one can contrive `51.6%` from `543781` and the remainder of the values in that data. If it's just a percentage of the total, then I get `12.84%`.